# befor the MainActivity shows in my app a white page shows in android

Tags: android

i wrote an app and my first activity is splash screen but befor this activity a null white page shows. how i can remove that?
this is my code

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    getActionBar().hide();
    delay=4000;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
    Intent intent_obj=new Intent(Splash.this,Content.class);
    startActivity(intent_obj);
    finish();
    }
    },delay);
```

Comment: Hardly surprising that you encounter a blank first up since you are loading the splash in a different thread. You don't need to and you shouldn't

Comment: Splash screens that are displayed purely for visual effect (i.e the app is not loading anything) are awful. Please don't force me to wait for an arbitrary amount of time before I can do what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

try adding your handler code in a separate function.

```
 public void splashTimer(int duration) {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent intent_obj = new Intent(Splash.this, Content.class);
            startActivity(intent_obj);
            finish();
        }
    }, duration);
}
```

and call it from the onCreate() method